# The concept of creating and correctly deploying modules, components, and subcomponents AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have trouble understanding the structure of the files for modules, components, directives, html templates.

If someone could explain me.

for example we have :

```
angular.module("app", [

// Module that contains shared modules 
"app.common",

// Feature-specific modules
"app.topMenu",
"app.sidebar",
"app.board"
]);
```

I created here separetely modules for topMenu, sidebar, board because they will have rich functionality.

I just start using components, so to the end I do not understand, how does it look like an example of such a module?

so, question is here **Do I think right?**

I will create file for example **sidebar-module.js**

inside it will seems like (this is example in my app will be more functions):

```
    (function(){


  angular
  .module('app.sidebar', [])
  .component('sidebar', {
    template: 
    `
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;">
      sidebar
      <add-person></add-person>
      <list-menu></list-menu>
      <colour-menu></colour-menu>
    </div>
    `
  })
  .component('addPerson', {
    template: `<div> 
      add Person  
      </div>`
  })
  .directive('listMenu', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: `<div>directiv with display list</div>`
    }
  })
  .directive('colourMenu', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: `<div>directiv with display menu colour</div>`
    }
  })
  .controller('SidebarCtrl', function(){});
})();
```

**1. should the module look like this with subcomponents?**

**2. and second question is if I have app.common for modules which is shared, so inside I should duplicate ??**

```
    angular
  .module('app.sidebar')
```

and to this create directives, components which I use this components/directives in many places??

Its should seems like? :

```
    (function(){

  angular
  .module('app.common', [])
  .component('login', {
    template: 
    `
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;"> 
    login comp
    </div>
    `
  }) 
  .component('addCard', {
    template: 
    `
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;"> 
     menu with adding card
    </div>
    `
  }) 
  .controller('commonCtrl', function(){});
})();
```

here are components which I can use in each page.

**So Do I think right, in the concept of creating modules??** 
I will create 2 files in folder with name components, inside will be this components app.common-module.js inside will be code number 2, and app.sidebar-module.js where inside will be code number 1(here private components which I use only in this component)

Answer (score 1):

According the angularjs doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

> we recommend that you break your application to multiple modules like
>   this:
>
> - A module for each feature
> - A module for each reusable component    (especially directives and filters)
> - And an application level module    which depends on the above modules and contains any initialization    code.

I will recommand you to read : https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#modularity

I think right but you should not duplicate any code. It will be not necessary since all that you declare in your main app script will be reusable.

Comment: Hey Can u expand this header ? : And an application level module which depends on the above modules and contains any initialization code.

Comment: It will be your main module : your code number 1, you have an exemple here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module  I update my answer

Comment: Hey ok , last question, if I have a few components and directives, I should hold them inside one file, all on one level, for example file(components) and inside search-directive.js, menu-component.js, user-login-component.js and if is 10 components and 10 directives I still should hold them inside 1 file yes?

Comment: It depends your application size but I will recommand you to have one file for each component or directive